# Meta Stack Exchange "return to main site" goes to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, meta, top-bar

On the new Meta Stack Exchange, if I select **help** from the top of the screen, the *Return to the main site* link goes to Stack Overflow, and the text says, "Back to Stack Overflow".

Shouldn't this say "Back to Stack Exchange" and link back to [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com)?